# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} for no apparent reason

Tags: xetex

I got the following errors when I compiled my code (based on xelatex). Please help me.

> 1. Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/skins'
> 2. Undefined control sequence. \tcolorboxenvironment
> 3. LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
> 4. LaTeX Error: Environment reviewer-comment undefined
> 5. LaTeX Error: \begin{response} on input line 55 ended by \end{reviewer-comment}

```
‎\documentclass[10pt]{article}‎

% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
% ‎\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}‎
\usepackage{microtype, xparse, tcolorbox}‎
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment}{}{}‎
\tcbuselibrary{skins}‎‎‎

\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment}{empty‎, ‎left=1em‎, ‎top=1ex‎, 
‎bottom=1ex‎, ‎borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black!20}‎,}
‎\ExplSyntaxOn‎
‎\NewDocumentEnvironment{response}‎{‎+‎m O{black!20}‎}{
\IfValueT{#1}‎{
\begin{reviewer-comment~}‎
\setlength\parindent{2em}‎
\noindent‎
‎\ttfamily #1‎
‎\end{reviewer-comment~}‎
}
\par\noindent\ignorespaces‎‎
}{‎\bigskip\par‎}

‎\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer {m}‎ {
\section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}‎
}
\ExplSyntaxOff‎
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}‎

% ‎You can get probably get rid of these definitions‎:
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}‎
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}‎

\title{Statement on the Revision of \meta{Paper ID} \\‎
Based on the Referees' Report}‎
\author{Author1 \and Author2 \and Author3}‎
\date{\today}‎


‎\begin{document}‎
‎This statement concerns our revision of the \meta{Paper ID} paper‎,
‎entitled \PaperTitle{\meta{Paper Title}}‎, ‎based on the referees'‎
‎report‎.

\Reviewer{\#1}‎
\begin{response}{First comment.}‎
Response to the first comment‎.
‎\end{response}‎
\begin{response}{Second comment.}‎
Response to the second comment‎.
‎\end{response}‎

‎\Reviewer{\#2}‎
‎\begin{response}{First comment.}‎
‎Response to the first comment‎.
‎\end{response}‎‎

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: You have several rather nasty invisible unicode chars in this code that you need to have removed before this MWE is usable, I get an error at the `\documentclass` line when copying the MWE to my editor and compiling it.

Comment: Are you working in an arabic or similar env? some of the chars at least pdflatex complains about are U+200e

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm working in an English environment.

Comment: Well, the other day I wrote a script to find non-latex supported chars in a text. It finds U+200E at least 60+ times in this MWE, as far as I understand U+200E is a marker that specifies that the writing direction from now on is left to right.

Comment: Interesting, I only just noticed your `xelatex` tag. Xelatex does not mention the bad unicode char, just croaks strange places. I cleaned it a little, now xelatex and pdflatex croak about the same line, but gives different error messages.

Comment: BTW: it might be an idea to change the title of this question as the that error message actually do not have anything to to with the actual problem.

Comment: The title is still not relevant see my last comment in my "answer", removing the 200E unicode chars and the two `~` there is no errors in that document. `/tcb/library/skins` just comes from the fact that xelatex sees bare chars in the preamble and is not particularly good at expressing what is wrong.

Comment: Please suggest an appropriate title.

Comment: "`LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}` for no apparent reason", might be better as I explained in my updated answer as it is the most important error in this MWE. I got hit by the 200E in an auto generated doc earlier this week, which is the only reason I knew about the issue. The skins library has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: We've had several others having issues with U+200E. Do you mind noting which editor your're using? Just so get can start narrowing in why we see these problems

Comment: Texpad Version 1.7.43 (210)

Comment: Interesting, the lasted one came from TeXStudio. It might be an idea to send them a feature request asking them for a way to visualize the location of invisible unicode chars. That would probably make it easier to figure out how those pesky chars get into the docs.

Comment: As a further investigation. The MWE you posted, did you write it from scratch? or was it copy and pasted from somewhere else?

Comment: It has been taken from https://github.com/s3rvac/blog/tree/master/en-2016-07-17-latex-template-for-responses-to-referees-reports

Comment: Hmm, copying directly from that `.tex` files i firefox does not appear to get any U+200E chars (and for some reason, I cannot clone the repo).

Answer (score 3):

Proper answer:

There are several things at play here. First of the MWE contains some 60+ invisible unicode chars (U+200E, LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK). Compiling the MWE with pdflatex causes an error about unicode 200E  being unknown to pdflatex.

In xelatex things are different, it knows about unicode and to it these invisible chars are just normal chars.

In the first line of the MWE, there is an U+200E at the end of the line. Xelatex will try to typeset this char, but is not allowed as we are in the preamble, hence the

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

You get the same error using `\documentclass{article} a`

The other error messages are presumably caused by your editor running in something like `nonstopmode` aka, if it gets an error try to recover,  that guess does not always go so well and errors may accumulated. Therefore one always concentrate on fixing the first error.

In the earlier text below. you'll find my markup of where the 200E chars are hiding in the doc.

Here is a cleaned version:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype, xparse, tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment}{}{}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment}{empty, left=1em, top=1ex, 
bottom=1ex, borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black!20},}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{response}{+m O{black!20}}{
\IfValueT{#1}{
\begin{reviewer-comment~}
\setlength\parindent{2em}
\noindent
\ttfamily #1
\end{reviewer-comment~}
}
\par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{\bigskip\par}

\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer {m} {
\section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}

% You can get probably get rid of these definitions:
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}

\title{Statement on the Revision of \meta{Paper ID} \\
Based on the Referees' Report}
\author{Author1 \and Author2 \and Author3}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
This statement concerns our revision of the \meta{Paper ID} paper,
entitled \PaperTitle{\meta{Paper Title}}, based on the referees'
report.

\Reviewer{\#1}
\begin{response}{First comment.}
Response to the first comment.
\end{response}
\begin{response}{Second comment.}
Response to the second comment.
\end{response}

\Reviewer{\#2}
\begin{response}{First comment.}
Response to the first comment.
\end{response}

\end{document}
```

Running this through xelatex we get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment reviewer-comment  undefined.
```

which is caused by defining that env as `reviewer-comment~` note the tilde at the end. Under `\ExplSyntaxOn` the char `~` is an explict space. So `reviewer-comment` is not defined whereas `reviewer-comment` (space at the end) is.

Just remove those two `~` and it works just fine.

BTW you are not using any code that needs `\ExplSyntaxOn` the interfaces explained in the `xparse` manual does not need it.

---

Earlier text:

---

Too long for comment, here is what the MWE looks like after I run it through my "look for unicode chars pdfLaTeX does not support", `\NOPE` just markes the position and the number of the char. All those `\NOPE{200e}` makes pdflatex croak. I have no idea what is wrong with your writing env since it adds all those otherwise hidden chars.

It seems pdflatex is a lot better at complaining about unicode issues than xelatex.

You can copy the MWE into https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html, to see what chars it is made of.

You get `U+200e LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK     &lrm;` all over the place. These are invisible, but counts as chars in the preamble by xelatex and lualatex so you get an error.

BTW If I remove the 200E chars from the MWE, and remove the `~` in `\begin/end{reviewer-comment~}‎`, then the MWE compiles just fine i both pdflatex and xelatex (testing under TeX Live 2018)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}\NOPE{200e}

% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
% \NOPE{200e}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\NOPE{200e}
\usepackage{microtype, xparse, tcolorbox}\NOPE{200e}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment}{}{}\NOPE{200e}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}\NOPE{200e}\NOPE{200e}\NOPE{200e}

\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment}{empty\NOPE{200e}, \NOPE{200e}left=1em\NOPE{200e}, \NOPE{200e}top=1ex\NOPE{200e}, 
\NOPE{200e}bottom=1ex\NOPE{200e}, \NOPE{200e}borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black!20}\NOPE{200e},}
\NOPE{200e}\ExplSyntaxOn\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}\NewDocumentEnvironment{response}\NOPE{200e}{\NOPE{200e}+\NOPE{200e}m O{black!20}\NOPE{200e}}{
\IfValueT{#1}\NOPE{200e}{
\begin{reviewer-comment~}\NOPE{200e}
\setlength\parindent{2em}\NOPE{200e}
\noindent\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}\ttfamily #1\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}\end{reviewer-comment~}\NOPE{200e}
}
\par\noindent\ignorespaces\NOPE{200e}\NOPE{200e}
}{\NOPE{200e}\bigskip\par\NOPE{200e}}

\NOPE{200e}\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer {m}\NOPE{200e} {
\section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}\NOPE{200e}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff\NOPE{200e}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}\NOPE{200e}

% \NOPE{200e}You can get probably get rid of these definitions\NOPE{200e}:
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}\NOPE{200e}
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}\NOPE{200e}

\title{Statement on the Revision of \meta{Paper ID} \\NOPE{200e}
Based on the Referees' Report}\NOPE{200e}
\author{Author1 \and Author2 \and Author3}\NOPE{200e}
\date{\today}\NOPE{200e}


\NOPE{200e}\begin{document}\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}This statement concerns our revision of the \meta{Paper ID} paper\NOPE{200e},
\NOPE{200e}entitled \PaperTitle{\meta{Paper Title}}\NOPE{200e}, \NOPE{200e}based on the referees'\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}report\NOPE{200e}.

\Reviewer{\#1}\NOPE{200e}
\begin{response}{First comment.}\NOPE{200e}
Response to the first comment\NOPE{200e}.
\NOPE{200e}\end{response}\NOPE{200e}
\begin{response}{Second comment.}\NOPE{200e}
Response to the second comment\NOPE{200e}.
\NOPE{200e}\end{response}\NOPE{200e}

\NOPE{200e}\Reviewer{\#2}\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}\begin{response}{First comment.}\NOPE{200e}
\NOPE{200e}Response to the first comment\NOPE{200e}.
\NOPE{200e}\end{response}\NOPE{200e}\NOPE{200e}

\NOPE{200e}\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: here is the MEW again, cleaned of all the U+200E's, run it through pdflatex or xelatex and the error is completely different, related to the `~` in the definition of `reviewer-comment~`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype, xparse, tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment}{}{}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment}{empty, left=1em, top=1ex, 
bottom=1ex, borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black!20},}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{response}{+m O{black!20}}{
\IfValueT{#1}{
\begin{reviewer-comment~}
\setlength\parindent{2em}
\noindent
\ttfamily #1
\end{reviewer-comment~}
}
\par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{\bigskip\par}

\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer {m} {
\section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}

% You can get probably get rid of these definitions:
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}

\title{Statement on the Revision of \meta{Paper ID} \\
Based on the Referees' Report}
\author{Author1 \and Author2 \and Author3}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
This statement concerns our revision of the \meta{Paper ID} paper,
entitled \PaperTitle{\meta{Paper Title}}, based on the referees'
report.

\Reviewer{\#1}
\begin{response}{First comment.}
Response to the first comment.
\end{response}
\begin{response}{Second comment.}
Response to the second comment.
\end{response}

\Reviewer{\#2}
\begin{response}{First comment.}
Response to the first comment.
\end{response}

\end{document}
```

The error you get with the U+200E in the document is related to the error you get if you type

```
\documentclass{article} a
```

That single `a` will cause an error like

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

as you are trying to typeset something in the preamble. pdflatex sees U+200E as an undefined char and complains. xelatex and lualatex klnows unicode and just sees it as a char (like `a`) tying to the typeset in the preamble.

The other error messages are probably artefacts because of the runmode your editor is using (ignoring errors).

Comment: Is your script somewhere available?

Comment: @albert no, it is a just a personal perl script

Comment: @albert basically you grab the unicode list from `utf8enc.dfu` and write a script that finds all chars outside of `ascii` plus that list. Of course, this will also hit Chinese etc, but right now we are jsut looking at latin-like scripts where there are strange chars that normally does not appear in a latin-like text.

Comment: Interesting list I found one at in my distribution .../texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8enc.dfu But still would you be willing to share it (as an as is script) with the community so others can benefit from it as well?

Comment: @albert not everyone have access to to perl. So an online tool is probably better, and as mentioned it only covers my needs, yours might differ and I do not want to maintain various tools.

Comment: I understand. That is why I did write as well "as an as is script", but not every user will respect that with as a result questions, questions, ...

Comment: Just leaving a comment here for other Emacs users, jbfu posted this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436116/3929, basically customize `glyphless-char-display-control` to use `format-control` = `acronym`, then those pesky invisible chars are visible in Emacs.