# fontenc causes error in appendix table of content

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

I am making a table of content for my appendices, but when I use `fontenc` a strange series of letters appears in the compiled pdf file.

my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\appendix

\etocdepthtag.toc{mtappendix}
\etocsettagdepth{mtchapter}{none}
\etocsettagdepth{mtappendix}{subsection}
\tableofcontents‎‎
\clearpage

\section{The first section}
\section{The second section}
\section{The third section}

\end{document}
```

Under the table of contents is a strange text appearing, as visible in the image below:
[image]

But this is not visible when I deactivate the `fontenc` package:

[image]

This is part of my thesis for which I really need the `fontenc` package. I believe that I cannot choose a different font without it. Is anybody able to help me out so I can use `fontenc` without the funny letters in my table of contents?

Comment: You have two evil `U+200E` characters after `\tableofcontents`. Remove the entire line and retype it. You can check with https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is caused by invisible Unicode characters in source and has nothing to do with fontenc, appendices or tables of contents.

Comment: if you had an editor with syntax highlighting, you would've seen that.

Comment: @naphaneal Not necessarily. I mainly use Notepad++ and TeXworks both of which have syntax highlighting for LaTeX and none of the two showed the evil characters. I also tried emacs and saw nothing. But I think Ulrike Fischer mentioned that WinEdt has a feature to warn you of suspicious characters.

Comment: @jfbu the output shown _is_ related to `fontenc` you would not get that output if the default OT1 font encoding were used, or if the input encoding had been declared as UTF-8.

Comment: @moewe or you can use the excellent web site that you linked too:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle agreed but then why not add the inputenc tag? (in fact I did earlier...) wait,  I though I did, maybe I dreamt.

Comment: @jfbu done:-)..

Comment: @moewe right, a mightier editor such as TXS would have. I saw two blank input characters. should have been less general and more specific in my comment.

Comment: @moewe in Emacs, you can customize `glyphless-char-display-control`. I just did and used `Display acronym` for the key `format-control`. It works...

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for investigating. Unfortunately, I don't really use Emacs enough or even understand it enough to know what you did.

Comment: @jfbu same OP?.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope not same OP, else this is akin to trolling... but perhaps caused by copy-paste from some same source somewhere ?

Comment: @moewe thank you for your reply. That helped! I did try to find a similar questions, but I am a new girl on the block and didn't find it.  I use TexStudio and I could not have seen the evil characters. I have added the inputenc. Anyway, I see how my is on topic but indeed a duplicate so I confirmed that.

Comment: @Linda I think this is the third time in 10days we've had issues with U+200E, so it is rather interesting to know the editor. TeXStudio noted

Comment: @Linda just wondering here: did you type this MWE entirely by hand or was some of it copy and pasted? (just trying to figure out why all of a sudden users start getting U+200E chars in their files).

Comment: @daleif yes, I copied the bit for an appendix table of contents from a online example. I do not remember which one actually, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are getting accent A typeset this is because you have UTF-8 character data in your file and you have a latex older than the 2018 release, and have not declared UTF-8 with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

which is required for older latex releases.

If you had declared to latex that you were using UTF-8 then you would have had an error message that U+200E is not set up for LaTeX,

The solution is to simply delete those characters from that line (as they are invisible control characters it may be easier to delete the line and retype it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed solved it by deleting the line, retype it. Also I added the package you advised! Saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

You have two  LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E) in your source right after the `\tableofcontents` command. Delete them.

Notice that when using Emacs you can make this obvious once the variable `glyphless-char-display-control` has been customized to use something else than thin space for such characters.[image]

Comment: +123 I needed that one last week